# Angular $http response returns null when print in console but successfully requested

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a local webservice developed with Spring, everything works fine (using browser or Postman), but when I try a simple GET method with Angular/Ionic it returns null in the response.

But when I look in the Net tab on Firebox console I see that the request was successfully made and returned the real JSON which is expected to return.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8081/jungery/card/getCard/1').success(function(response) {
  console.log('Response:', response); // response is null
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log('Error:', data);
});
```

Network tab on Firefox:
[image]

When debugging on the server side I can confirm that the method on the webservice was really called.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCard/{id}", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.OPTIONS }, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public Card getCardById(@PathVariable int id) {
    Card item = cardService.getCard(id);
    if (item == null) {
        item = new Card();
        item.setId(0L);
    }
    return item;
}
```

So, my question is: What am I missing here? I had done this before and never had such a strange behavior like this.

Comment: `success` and `error` are deprecated (see $http docs)...try using `then()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ensured that your webservice works ok, it's probably client's fault.

Try "then" instead of "success".

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8081/jungery/card/getCard/1').then(function(response) {
    console.log('Response:', response);
}, function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Error:', data);
});
```

You can read more why this approach is preferred here:
http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/
Also when consuming REST services with AngularJS you may consider using Restangular: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Comment: I changed as you suggested the result changed but no good yet, now it says:
09:09:00.147 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:8081/jungery/card/getCard/1’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’). 1 (unknown)

And the response is printed as an object but the data is null:

Response: Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" } 

Look at the status

Comment: If you use firefox, this addon might be helpful.
[CORS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)